# How do I know what standard formats the compiler supports?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards

I know one format is  "IEEE 754 floating point standard"

To check if a C++ compiler uses the IEEE 754 floating point standard or not

```
 std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559;
```

What other standard formats are there?
How do I check that the C++ compiler is following that format or not?

EDIT : how many Types of Format are there ? what are they ? in terms of c++ Language

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @aix: to know the clear idea regarding the formats ..other than IEEE Floating format

Comment: @Vijay: doesn't work for portable code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't, `numeric_limits` is clearly designed with IEEE 754 in mind. You only get to know if the implementation is IEEE 754 compliant, or not.

But keep in mind that you should use `has_infinity`, `has_quiet_NaN` etc. to check for individual features - basically, you check for certain features, not for specific floating point formats.

Answer (score 2):

It's in general *not a good idea* to realy on `std::numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559`, because with g++ this is true even when your code is compiled with fastmath option, which e.g. does not support IEEE 754 NaN behavior (it's mostly just binary level compatible representation).

I.e., in practice `is_iec559` does not tell you whether the implementation is IEEE 754-compliant or not.

So, you're down to compiler-specific means.

Cheers & hth.,